# how to run a 3hrs long backend process on firebase function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

how to run a 3hrs long backend process in firebase function?

this process need about 3 hrs to complete but I always get timeout in 1hr.

```
exports.resyncpostsdata = FunctionsV2
    .https
    .onRequest( 
        {
            timeoutSeconds: 3600, // 1hr
        },
        async (req:any, res:any) => {
            await ResyncPostsData(req, res);
        }
);
```

Comment: Nothing native. But I wrote something that can help you: https://medium.com/google-cloud/long-running-job-with-cloud-workflows-38b57bea74a5

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Cloud Functions Gen 2 can run up to only 1 hour as mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/2nd-gen/overview#whats_new). If you need to run longer processes, I'd recommend checking out [Cloud Compute](https://cloud.google.com/compute).